# Is it possible to find out what series/shape/variants have been loaded by fontspec?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, truetype

I have a large collection of old TrueType fonts from various CDs bought over the years which I now need to use with XeLaTeX and `fontspec` (previously I used the Type 1 fonts converted for use with PdfLaTeX).

If I now say (for example) `\setsansfont{Zurich}` it loads Bitstream's clone of Univers, but the default bold is set to Bold Condensed. Zurich is given in the fontnames for the whole family as an alternate name; they also have groups with names like Zurich Lt BT, Zurich BT, and so on, which are clear enough, but I have no way to tell if `fontspec` has loaded them all or just a subset.

Is there a way in `fontspec` to show what exact series, shapes, and variants have been found and loaded by a `\set<whatever>font` command? There seem to be commands to tell `fontspec` what to load when you already know what names to use; what I'm looking for is what `fontspec` believes is available.